# Base class for ascx and aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an entity Profile that I need to access from all aspx and ascx pages in my website. I have created a class "Context" which has the profile property and inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. This worked very well for aspx pages.

I need to apply the same parent to the user controls in my application, my only choice now is to create another Context class "UserControlContext" that inherits from System.Web.UI.UserControls and  let the user controls inherit from it.

My problem is that this way i'm duplicating the  code for both context pages, how can I use one Context class to let both ascx and aspx inherit from ? What type will that Context class be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Your control is either a [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)). They can't share the same base class.

I suggest to move the duplicate code into another class that is called by both `Page` and `Control`. You can use the base class `Control` if you want to in that class, so the code is as generic as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit only from one class in C# so you can't put the functionality into a common base class for both (as they already inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page` and `System.Web.UI.UserControl`). What you can do is to move the common functionality out to some other class and then use that class inside your `Context` and `UserControlContext` classes. You would not derive directly from the new class, but you could encapsulate it inside both `Context` and `UserControlContext` classes and call its methods from those classes.

When it comes to the question to which extent you can move the code out to the other class, that depends on your code.